# How should I fetch data from server for recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a question about sending and receiving data from server in Kotlin and Java.
I have a json array with 10000 records that I want to show them in a recyclerview.
Should I fetch data part by part for example first I fetch 500 numbers of data then fetch next 500 numbers and go on, or I can fetch all data and then show them in a recyclerview?
Will be server down if I get all data together?
Imagine 50 or 100 users that run the application in same time.

I have searched a lot about that but I couldn't find anything about that.

Comment: If the server can handle all? Well you have a nice opportunity to test that. Do it! We dont know what kind of server you have so how can we advise?